# I want to Login through Vipps App, i tried many solution but not succeed

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway

I'm facing trouble on login with vipps application, i simply want user sign-up with vipps app just like gmail, facebook etc....

anyone have any solution please share with me !

I tried to find solution but not succeeded yet!